# Issue with datatype Money in SQL SERVER vs string

Tags: sql-server, string, type-conversion, money-format

I have a spreadsheet that gets all values loaded into SQL Server. One of the fields in the spreadsheet happens to be money. Now in order for everything to be displayed correcctly - i added a field in my tbl with Money as DataType.

When i read the value from spreadsheet I pretty much store it as a String, such as this... **"94259.4"**. When it get's inserted in sql server it looks like this **"94259.4000"**. Is there a way for me to basically get rid of the 0's in the sql server value when I grab it from DB - because the issue I'm running across is that - even though these two values are the same - because they are both compared as Strings - it thinks that there not the same values.

I'm foreseeing another issue when the value might look like this...**94,259.40**  I think what might work is limiting the numbers to 2 after the period. So as long as I select the value from Server with this format 94,259.40 - I thin I should be okay.

EDIT:

```
For Column = 1 To 34
    Select Case Column
        Case 1  'Field 1
           If Not ([String].IsNullOrEmpty(CStr(excel.Cells(Row, Column).Value)) Or CStr(excel.Cells(Row, Column).Value) = "") Then
  strField1 = CStr(excel.Cells(Row, Column).Value)
           End If
        Case 2 'Field 2
        ' and so on
```

I go through each field and store the value as a string. Then I compare it against the DB and see if there is a record that has the same values. The only field in my way is the Money field.

Comment: What tool are you using to load the spreadsheet into the SQL Server?

Comment: Ugly lesson learned long ago: Never, never, never, NEVER, EVER, eVeR, use the MONEY data type in SQL Server. It makes puppies hurt and causes imbalance in the universe.

Comment: @user3272686 - no tool just opening the spreadsheet and grabbing values (specifying fields, etc)

Comment: There has to be some mechanism that's transferring spreadsheet data to SQL Server...

Comment: What steps do you take to import the data from the spreadsheet? I just need a better understanding to help you

Comment: @Bobski *never* use money. ***Never*** store numeric or date data as text. As long as you use the wrong data types and don't explain how the data got into SQL Server, it's impossible to help. BTW Excel **doesn't have types**. Only text formatting styles. It's all text or numbers. Fix the table types and change your loading tool or process to parse and load numeric data correctly. All tools allow you to import numbers specifying their format or collation

Comment: @user3272686 - see EDIT

Comment: Hyperbolic comments aside, money is a perfectly valid data type, and sometimes the prudent choice.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti - it was not my choice to store is as such. It was developed by a programmer long gone from here - I'm trying to build the excel function as an addition and have got to deal with this thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Format() to compare strings, or even Float  For example:

```
Declare @YourTable table (value money)
Insert Into @YourTable values
(94259.4000),
(94259.4500),
(94259.0000)

Select Original  = value
      ,AsFloat   = cast(value as float)
      ,Formatted = format(value,'0.####')
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
Original    AsFloat     Formatted
94259.40    94259.4     94259.4
94259.45    94259.45    94259.45
94259.00    94259       94259
```

I should note that Format() has some great functionality, but it is NOT known for its performance

Answer (score 0):

The core issue is that string data is being used to represent numeric information, hence the problems comparing "123.400" to "123.4" and getting mismatches. They *should* mismatch. They're strings.

The solution is to store the data in the spreadsheet in its proper form - numeric, and then select a proper format for the database - which is NOT the "Money" datatype (insert shudders and visions of vultures circling overhead).  Otherwise, you are going to have an expanding kluge of conversions between types as you go back and forth between two improperly designed solutions, and finding more and more edge cases that "don't quite work," and require more special cases...and so on.

Comment: Fair enough! Was not developed by me, need it to work. Don't think I can change datatypes - too deep in.

Comment: Fair enough backatcha :)  Can you post the query you're using to pull data from your table (for the comparisons)?